# Use libgdx or surfaceview for this

Tags: android, libgdx

I am planning to do an app that involves triangle colliding with circle. Also determining how fast the user touches the circle while it is is moving.

I am already experienced with android development (but limited on drawing but knows the basic). Should I go with surface view drawing or should I start learning libgdx for the above purpose? And what would be the rational "so it is not vague/opinionated question"

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to go with **libgdx**. It is very well designed, well documented and has a friendly community which will help you to *quickly get started*.

Furthermore it will be *a lot easier to render graphics* elements, which would be a lot more difficult with "pure" Android/OpenGL.

Another great feature you might be interested in is that *libgdx has a Box2D extension*, which might help you with the triangle/sphere collisions, if you are planning something more advanced here.

And last but not least libgdx would be my preferred way of developing a game, because I can *develop it on desktop* and then just deploy and test it on my mobile device.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. So the learning curve is not that steep I assume eh? The only concern I have is that I read on the Internet that you have to do the whole thing in Libgdx. Meaning you can't creating main page, settings, other activities in normal Android and call Libgdx for the game itself. Is this true? It will be a hassle doing every button, dialog,.. Etc from scratch by drawing as opposed to using views and the default Android sdk.. What do you think?

Comment: That's correct, in general. It is still possible to use native android e. g. via [interfacing](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code), but mixing it is probably one of the more advanced topics.